# Unity3d Transform issues when trying to re-parent a Gameobject with sub-Gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to grab a Gameobject that's placed in the correct spot and re-parent it to different Gameobject transforms using code. I manage to do this by using ..transform.parent = parent.transform but the rotation and position get messed up. How can I keep it's rotation and position when re-parenting?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "messed up"? Does transform.localPosition or transform.position change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `gameObject.transform.SetParent(anotherGameObject)`, or you risk exactly the sort of phenomena you've described. See `SetParent` [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html); there is a second parameter to consider.

The form mentioned in the question still works in many cases, but has been deprecated for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Place all game object that you want to  parent, to empty game object(example:"EMPTY\PARENT\EMPTY\CHILD") with scale 1:1:1(in editor)or re-scale your parent game object to 1:1:1